# Union of ordered sets in entity framework and then skip

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a table of lessons, and I want to perform a text search over several fields of it. However the search should be ordered: for example lesson have a `Keywords` field and `Description` field.  The search should give a priority over values found by `Keywords`. Everything should be also ordered by date but only after the priority is considered.

I'm also using `ToPagedList()` in the end from https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList (I think it just uses `Skip()` and `Top()` to manage pages)

This is what I have so far:

```
string[] word = /*Search words*/
var data = db.LessonsLearneds.Where(dbRecord => words.Any(word =>
        dbRecord.SearchKeywords.StartsWith(word + ",") ||
        dbRecord.SearchKeywords.Contains("," + word + ",") ||
        dbRecord.SearchKeywords.EndsWith("," + word)))
        .Select(x => new { Record = x, Order = 1 });

data = data.Union(
    db.LessonsLearneds
        .Where(dbRecord => words.Any(word => dbRecord.Title.Contains(word)))
        .Select(x => new { Record = x, Order = 2 }));

data = data.Union(
     db.LessonsLearneds
        .Where(dbRecord => words.Any(word => dbRecord.Description.Contains(word)))
        .Select(x => new { Record = x, Order = 3}));

data = data.Union(
     db.LessonsLearneds
        .Where(dbRecord => words.Any(word => dbRecord.Lesson.Contains(word)))
        .Select(x => new { Record = x, Order = 4 }));

return data
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
            .ThenByDescending(x => x.Record.Date)
            .Select(x => x.Record)
            .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

Overall this code does almost what I want, except of `Distinct()`. Each union here can retrieve the same record, so I may receive it several times, and `Distinct()` does not forces the uniqueness because of virtual `Order` field. I cannot put `Distinct` after `Select(x => x.Record)` because of `ToPagedList(..)` which requires the set to be ordered (results in: `The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities.` exception)

Any ideas?

I have one so far: to add `Order` field after I `Distinct`, but this means that I will have to write those Contains checks twice which I think is very ugly solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since you are projecting unique records due to the different `Order` value, replace the `Union` operator with `Concat` (which is the LINQ equivalent of the SQL `UNION ALL`).

```
string[] word = /*Search words*/
var data = db.LessonsLearneds.Where(dbRecord => words.Any(word =>
        dbRecord.SearchKeywords.StartsWith(word + ",") ||
        dbRecord.SearchKeywords.Contains("," + word + ",") ||
        dbRecord.SearchKeywords.EndsWith("," + word)))
        .Select(x => new { Record = x, Order = 1 });

data = data.Concat(
    db.LessonsLearneds
        .Where(dbRecord => words.Any(word => dbRecord.Title.Contains(word)))
        .Select(x => new { Record = x, Order = 2 }));

data = data.Concat(
     db.LessonsLearneds
        .Where(dbRecord => words.Any(word => dbRecord.Description.Contains(word)))
        .Select(x => new { Record = x, Order = 3}));

data = data.Concat(
     db.LessonsLearneds
        .Where(dbRecord => words.Any(word => dbRecord.Lesson.Contains(word)))
        .Select(x => new { Record = x, Order = 4 }));
```

Then replace the `Distinct` with `GroupBy` using `x.Record` as a key and taking  min `Order` for each grouping, and do the rest as in your current query:

```
return data
     .GroupBy(x => x.Record)
     .Select(g => new { Record = g.Key, Order = g.Min(x => x.Order) })
     .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
     .ThenByDescending(x => x.Record.Date)
     .Select(x => x.Record)
     .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `Distinct` with `GroupBy` and `Select`, like this:

```
return data
        .GroupBy(x => x.Record)
        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ThenByDescending(x => x.Record.Date).First())
        .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Record.Date)
        .Select(x => x.Record)
        .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

The unfortunate side effect of this approach is that you need to repeat `OrderBy` inside the first `Select`, but it should produce the results that you are looking for.